# Быстрый поиск по текстовому файлу. ESP32

Tags: поиск, esp32, sd

Есть задача: организовать что-то вроде пропускной системы. За основу взята `ESP32` с подключенной SD-картой, на которой хранится текстовый файл. Файл может содержать в себе до 500000 строк вида `38DD7B724386D98E`. После считывания метки (условно, пропуска) производится поиск строки в файле и, при совпадении, предоставляются те или иные доступы, выполняются те или иные действия. Соответственно, необходимо организовать быстрый поиск по файлу. На первых этапах, больше для обучения, т.к. контроллер для меня новый, разработка под ESP производится через `Arduino IDE` с соответствующей библиотекой. Исполнение стандартного `File.find` занимает > 5 минут, что, конечно, нереально долго, данное действие должно выполняться за < 2 сек. Собственно, как лучше подойти к решению этого вопроса? Какие алгоритмы и библиотеки будут применимы и актуальны в данном случае? Подсказывали, что можно проиндексировать массив или использовать метод половинного деления, но не могу понять, как применить это на текущей платформе.

P.S. Смена платформы или какое-то использование иного подхода пока, к сожалению, не рассматривается, требование такое. ESP32, SD-карта, 500000 строк на карте.

Comment: На сколько понял, строки имеют одинаковую длину. Отсортировать, записать, использовать бинарный поиск. Если представить строку как HEX-последовательность, то если перевести ее в бинарный формат, то будет еще быстрей, да и занимать меньше места.

Comment: Всеравно 8 мегабайт это много. Для полмиллиона человек можно и сервер попросить.

Comment: @eri, а сервер есть, но обязательно должен быть вариант, когда система способна обойтись и без сервера. Собственно, проблема этого вопроса уже решена, для этого сервер, на основе сортированного файла, подготавливает массив индексов и раз в определенный период эти данные на самой esp обновляются, при необходимости. ~30ms занимает такой поиск без каких-либо ухищрений